# How to make the test pass from the fixture in pytest

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am using pytest in a way in which there are two execution paths , one to configure the test environment (create some buildable folders, such as a c application that needs to be cross compiled and executed later in a distant target), and the second path that will execute the test.
I am having this separation because we need to separate the build and the execution processes so that they can be run separately by different machines in a CI environment.

so in the Configuration phase (controlled using a pytest cli argument), I am simply skipping the tests in a fixture that checks if this is the configuration stage or not, using:

```
pytest.skip("configuration stage")
```

What I want to do is to make the test appear as PASSED during the configuration stage, from the fixture context (without going to the test), putting an assert will not suffice as the test function will be executed anyway, and I don't want to pollute all the tests with a check like this:

```
def test_function(config_fixture):
    if config_fixture:
       assert True
    else:
      #run the test
```

Comment: assert `True == True`?   if not care here.

Comment: if executed in the fixture, the test will still be executed, which is not what I want.